# Synchronise TFS database with workspaces (put not get)

Tags: tfs

We had a corruption in our TFS database and had to restore it to a previous time. This caused our workspaces to be 'in the future' and our TFS server to be 'in the past'. I tried to do a check in so that VS would update TFS to the latest version but it only checked in the files I had modified since the last check in.

Since the last check-in was after the last backup and is now gone, **how do I synchronise TFS so that it has the lastest version which is on my machine**?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to perform "add items to folder" action instead of "check in pending changes"

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easier way but in the past this has worked fairly well.

1. Make a full copy of your local
2. Do a complete get latest/force/overwrite
3. Checkout the entire folder
4. Overwrite the working folder with your copy
5. Use a diff tool (or whatever method you want) to do the manual adds/deletes to TFS that won't come in when you copy
6. Check in the entire folder (only the changed files will mark in history) - a comment like "fixing corruption" is helpful for the future

Files will all be in TFS and up to date. Obviously history/labels/merges/etc are gone.